# How to print regex pattern as string in terminal?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, terminal

I'm trying to write a regex string in the terminal but `zsh` is interpreting this regex instead of just printing it. My shell code:

```
echo "((https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www)))?[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})"
```

Current output:

```
zsh: event not found: www)))?[a
```

I already tried to use simple quotes, double quotes and no quotes.

Comment: `!` has special meaning to `zsh` except in single quoted strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type this command in a file and run as a script, it should be fine, unless you have explicitly enabled history expansion in your script. But then, you know what you are doing.

If you really literally hack such a huge command manually into an interactive shell, either turn off history expansion (by `setopt nobanghist`), or prefix your `!` by a `\` (unless the `!` is already between single-quotes).

Example: Typing `echo !www` won't work, but typing `echo \!www` will.

If you never use history expansion, turning it off permanently would probably be the best choice.